# Multiple Prompts for iOS Facebook Account Access

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am attempting to add facebook integration into a project. In iOS 6+, I request access to the user's facebook accounts with the following code.

```
if (self.accountStore == nil) self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountTypeFacebook = [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
[self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountTypeFacebook options:options
    completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted) {
            self.accountsArray = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountTypeFacebook];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self updateTable:self.accountsArray];
            });
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error: %@",error);                                               
        }
    }];
```

If the user selects "cancel" in the modal popup that prompts for access to Facebook accounts, is it possible to prompt the user again the next time the app needs this access?

Currently, if the user first selects "cancel", the user must then go into the Settings app and manually change the permission to use facebook within the app. I am not attempting to change this permission directly, I just want to prompt the user for access multiple times.

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: It's not doable, as the user said no, and the OS is respecting their choice. Wanting to accomplish what you're asking is user-choice hostile.